Efficient Large Byte Transfer Using MultipeerConnectivity in Swift
Description
My goal is to generate large data on one device, transfer it to another using streams, and save it to disk. To optimize memory usage, I plan to generate and send smaller chunks sequentially.
Assume the transferred file size is up to 1.5GB.
Current Implementation
My core MultipeerConnectivity logic is encapsulated in the MultipeerService class. Key parts are as follows:
class MultipeerService: NSObject, ObservableObject, MCSessionDelegate, MCNearbyServiceBrowserDelegate, MCNearbyServiceAdvertiserDelegate {
    var inputStreamDelegate: DataReceiver?
    ...
    func startStreaming(withName streamName: String, to peer: MCPeerID) throws -> OutputStream {
        return try session.startStream(withName: streamName, toPeer: peer)
    }

    public func session(_ session: MCSession, didReceive stream: InputStream, withName streamName: String, fromPeer peerID: MCPeerID) {
        log.info("Started receiving stream '\(streamName)'")
        self.inputStreamDelegate?.readStream(stream, withName: streamName)
    }
}

Sending Data
The DataSender class handles generating bytes and writing them to the stream:
class DataSender: NSObject, StreamDelegate, ObservableObject {
    private var multipeerService: MultipeerService
    private var outputStream: OutputStream?
    private let chunkSize = 1024 // 1KB chunk size
    private var totalSize: Int = 0
    @Published var bytesSent: Int = 0

    init(ms: MultipeerService = MultipeerService.shared) {
        self.multipeerService = ms
        super.init()
    }

    // Called from UI
    func startStreaming(peer: MCPeerID, sizeMB: Int) {
        do {
            let outputStream = try multipeerService.startStreaming(withName: "Test", to: peer)
            self.outputStream = outputStream
            outputStream.delegate = self
            outputStream.schedule(in: .main, forMode: .common)
            outputStream.open()

            self.totalSize = sizeMB * 1024 * 1024 // convert MB to bytes
            self.bytesSent = 0
        } catch {
            fatalError("Error starting stream: \(error)")
        }
    }

    private func sendRandomData() {
        guard let outputStream = outputStream else { return }

        while outputStream.hasSpaceAvailable && bytesSent < totalSize {
            let currentChunkSize = min(chunkSize, totalSize - bytesSent)
            var buffer = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count: currentChunkSize)
            _ = SecRandomCopyBytes(kSecRandomDefault, currentChunkSize, &buffer)

            let bytesWritten = outputStream.write(buffer, maxLength: currentChunkSize)
            if bytesWritten > 0 {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.bytesSent += bytesWritten
                }
                print("Bytes written: \(bytesWritten) | Total: \(bytesSent)")
            } else {
                if let error = outputStream.streamError {
                    print("Stream Error: \(error)")
                    closeStream()
                    return
                }
            }
        }

        if bytesSent >= totalSize {
            closeStream()
        }
    }

    private func closeStream() {
        print("Closing stream")
        outputStream?.close()
        outputStream?.remove(from: .main, forMode: .default)
        outputStream = nil
    }

    // StreamDelegate methods
    func stream(_ aStream: Stream, handle eventCode: Stream.Event) {
        print("Stream called: \(eventCode)")
        switch eventCode {
        case .hasSpaceAvailable:
            print("hasSpaceAvailable")
            sendRandomData()
        case .endEncountered:
            print("Stream end encountered")
            closeStream()
        case .errorOccurred:
            if let error = aStream.streamError {
                print("Stream Error: \(error)")
            }
            closeStream()
        default:
            break
        }
    }
}

Receiving Data
The DataReceiver class reads the stream and writes it to a file:
class DataReceiver: NSObject, StreamDelegate, ObservableObject {
    private var multipeerService: MultipeerService
    private var inputStream: InputStream?
    private var fileHandle: FileHandle?

    @Published var received: Int = 0

    init(ms: MultipeerService = MultipeerService.shared) {
        self.multipeerService = ms
        super.init()

        self.multipeerService.inputStreamDelegate = self
    }

    // Called by MultipeerService when stream is received
    public func readStream(_ stream: InputStream, withName streamName: String) {
        stream.delegate = self
        stream.schedule(in: .main, forMode: .default)
        stream.open()
        self.inputStream = stream

        // Prepare to write to file
        if let fileURL = createFileInLibrary(withName: streamName) {
            do {
                fileHandle = try FileHandle(forWritingTo: fileURL)
            } catch {
                print("Error opening file handle: \(error)")
            }
        }
    }

    // StreamDelegate method to handle input stream events
    func stream(_ aStream: Stream, handle eventCode: Stream.Event) {
        print("Stream function called. EventCode: \(eventCode)")
        switch eventCode {
        case .hasBytesAvailable:
            if aStream == inputStream {
                readAvailableBytes(stream: aStream as! InputStream)
            }
        case .endEncountered:
            closeStream()
        case .errorOccurred:
            if let error = aStream.streamError {
                print("Stream Error: \(error)")
            }
            closeStream()
        default:
            break
        }
    }

    private func readAvailableBytes(stream: InputStream) {
        let bufferSize = 1024
        var buffer = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count: bufferSize)

        while stream.hasBytesAvailable {
            let numberOfBytesRead = stream.read(&buffer, maxLength: bufferSize)
            print("Number of bytes read: \(numberOfBytesRead)")
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.received += numberOfBytesRead
            }

            if numberOfBytesRead < 0 {
                if let error = stream.streamError {
                    print("Stream read error: \(error)")
                    return
                }
            }

            // Write to file
            if let fileHandle = fileHandle {
                fileHandle.write(Data(bytes: buffer, count: numberOfBytesRead))
            }
        }
    }

    private func closeStream() {
        inputStream?.close()
        inputStream?.remove(from: .current, forMode: .default)
        inputStream = nil

        fileHandle?.closeFile()
        fileHandle = nil
    }

    private func createFileInLibrary(withName name: String) -> URL? {
        let fileManager = FileManager.default
        guard let libraryDirectory = fileManager.urls(for: .libraryDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first else {
            print("Could not find library directory")
            return nil
        }

        let fileURL = libraryDirectory.appendingPathComponent("\(name).data")
        fileManager.createFile(atPath: fileURL.path, contents: nil, attributes: nil)

        return fileURL
    }
}

Problem
The first peer sends about 17,000 bytes and then stops, while the second peer reads only about 2,000 bytes and stops. Additionally, if I use .current instead of .main for stream.schedule, the StreamDelegate is never called.
Console output from the receiver peer
Stream function called. EventCode: NSStreamEvent(rawValue: 1)
Stream function called. EventCode: NSStreamEvent(rawValue: 2)
Number of bytes read: 1024
Number of bytes read: 1024
Number of bytes read: 142

Question
How can I achieve the desired outcome of streaming large data efficiently between devices using MultipeerConnectivity? Any advice or solutions to the issues I'm facing would be greatly appreciated.
